# Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.?

Tags: c#, arrays

Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds <- what is this error???

how can i fix it?
This error occur after i add Array.Copy

i have no idea....

```
static byte[] sendData = new byte[5];
static int sendCount = 0;
    
try
{
 
    Console.Write("->");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();

    foreach(string s in text.Split(' '))
    {
        if(null != s && "" != s)
        {
            sendData[sendCount++] = Convert.ToByte(s, 16);
        }
    }

    byte[] LRC = new byte[1];
    LRC = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)sendData[2] ^ sendData[3] ^ sendData[4]);
    
    byte[] hexData = new byte[sendData.Length + LRC.Length];
    Array.Copy(sendData, 0, hexData, 0, 5);  // <-- error occurs this point
    Array.Copy(LRC, 0, hexData, hexData.Length + 1, 1);//<-or this point
    
    port.Write(hexData, 0, hexData.Length);
    
    Array.Clear(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
    Array.Clear(LRC, 0, LRC.Length);
    Array.Clear(hexData, 0, hexData.Length);
    sendCount = 0;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Check Data");
}
```

Comment: There's simply _far too many things_ that you're doing wrong in your code...

Comment: @Dai It hasn't been long since I studied C#, so I guess there are a lot of mistakes. I need to learn harder.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering on concrete question, the definition of the copy method:

```cs
public static void Copy (
    Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex,
    Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex,
    int length);
```

In your case

```cs
Array.Copy(LRC, 0, hexData, hexData.Length + 1, 1);
```

So, you are trying to copy bytes to array `hexData` to the index `hexData.Length + 1` that is basically out of its boundaries.

I have no idea what you are trying to implement, but you should make sure that destination index during the copy is less or equal than `hexData.Length - 1` (also taking into account the length).

Comment: It hasn't been long since I studied C#, so I guess there are a lot of mistakes. I need to learn harder.... Thank u for you answer! :)